# git stash --all not stashing untracked dir

Tags: git, git-stash

I have some untracked files and folders in my project. When I run "git stash --all" even though these untracked folders not stashed why so? How can I fix this?

```
/home/bug_fix/mps>git stash --all 
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in mps-dashboard/dashboard/veronica-client/target/generated-sources/swagger/.gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in mps-dashboard/dashboard/veronica-client/target/generated-sources/swagger/.swagger-codegen-ignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: failed to remove mps-dashboard/dashboard/webapp-frontend/target/we-archiver/pom.properties: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove mps-dashboard/dashboard/webapp-frontend/target/mps-dash-fe-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: Permission denied


/home/bug_fix/mps>git status
On branch mps
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mps'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    test/veronica/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

added more log as asked by @Ruchita Sheth

```
/home/bug_fix/mps>git status
On branch mps
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mps'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        test/veronica/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
/home/bug_fix/mps>


/home/bug_fix/mps>git stash push --all
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in ric-dashboard/dashboard/webapp-frontend/node/npm.cmd.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
Ignoring path test/veronica/
Saved working directory and index state WIP on mps: f80fc826a Merge branch 'XLM-908' into 'mps'
warning: failed to remove ric-dashboard/dashboard/app-mgr-client/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst: Permission denied
warning: failed to remove ric-dashboard/dashboard/webapp-frontend/target/ric-dash-fe-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: Permission denied
/home/bug_fix/mps>


/home/bug_fix/mps>git status
On branch mps
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mps'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    test/veronica/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: you are missing "push" or "save". try `git stash push --all` . Here is the reference link https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt--a

Comment: @RuchitaSheth it is still not working.

Comment: I just tried `git stash --all` and it stashed untracked files in an untracked subdirectory too. Do you get the same problem in other sandboxes? What version of Git are you using? You did get several warnings, does `git stash list` show that your stash operation actually happened?

Comment: In addition to the questions @joanis asked: is `test/veronica/` the working tree of a *different* Git repository? If that's the case you *cannot* add its files as Git will not let you put in the contents of some other repository.

Comment: @myquest4 sh it will not display in stash list. whenever you unstash it, all untrack files will be there

Comment: @RuchitaSheth even after stashing, i see untracked files in git status?  did stashing not go well? i suspect something related to warning but not sure why?

Comment: @myquest4sh can you add a snap for `git status` then `git stash push --all` and then `git status` again.

Comment: @RuchitaSheth i have added the logs as asked by you. i see there is a line in the output "Ignoring path test/veronica/"    what is that?

Comment: @myquest4sh that is the path that is being ignored explicitly by the .gitignore file. you might added a file or a folder in a directory that is being ignored by .gitignore.

Comment: this is the reason your `git stash push --all` not adding untracked file.